# why pytz.country_timezones('cn') in centos system have different result?

Tags: timezone, country, pytz

Two computer install centos 6.5, kernel is 3.10.44, have different result. 
one result is `[u'Asia/Shanghai', u'Asia/Urumqi']`, and the other is `['Asia/Shanghai', 'Asia/Harbin', 'Asia/Chongqing', 'Asia/Urumqi', 'Asia/Kashgar']`.

**Is there any config that make the first result same as the second result?**

I have following python code:

```
def get_date():
    date = datetime.utcnow()
    from_zone = pytz.timezone("UTC")
    to_zone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Urumqi")
    date = from_zone.localize(date)
    date = date.astimezone(to_zone)

    return date

def get_curr_time_stamp():
    date = get_date()
    stamp = time.mktime(date.timetuple())

    return stamp
 cur_time = get_curr_time_stamp()
 print "1", time.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time()))
 print "2", time.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(cur_time))
```

When use this code to get time, the result of one computer(have 2 results) is:

```
1 2016 04 20 08:53:18
2 2016 04 20 06:53:18
```

and the other(have 5 results) is:

```
1 2016 04 20 08:53:18
2 2016 04 20 08:53:18
```

**I don't know why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just have an outdated version of pytz on the system returning five time zones (or perhaps on both systems).  You can find the latest releases [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz#downloads).  It's important to stay on top of time zone updates, as the various governments of the world change their time zones often.

Like most systems, pytz gets its data from the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  The five time zones for China were reduced to two in version 2014f (corresponding to pytz 2014.6).  From [the release notes](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2014-August/000023.html):

> China's five zones have been simplified to two, since the post-1970
>        differences in the other three seem to have been imaginary.  The
>        zones Asia/Harbin, Asia/Chongqing, and Asia/Kashgar have been
>        removed; backwards-compatibility links still work, albeit with
>        different behaviors for time stamps before May 1980.  Asia/Urumqi's
>        1980 transition to UTC+8 has been removed, so that it is now at
>        UTC+6 and not UTC+8.  (Thanks to Luther Ma and to Alois Treindl;
>        Treindl sent helpful translations of two papers by Guo Qingsheng.)

Also, you may wish to read Wikipedia's [Time in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_China) article, which explains that the `Asia/Urumqui` entry is for "Ürümqi Time", which is used unofficially in some parts of the Xinjiang region.  This zone is not recognized by the Chinese government, and is considered a politically charged issue.  As such, many systems choose to omit the Urumqi time zone, despite it being in listed in the tz database.

Comment: Thank you, I use python to get time, but have different result. Do you why?

Comment: I answered that in the first sentence.